# Templates & unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++

let's say I am trying to do something like this:

**header.h:**

```
template <typename T>
class foo { 
private: 
    // members...
public:
    foo();
    ~foo();
}
```

**source.cpp:**

```
template <typename T>
foo::foo() {
    // do something... 
}

template <typename T>
foo::~foo() {
    // do something... 
}
```

but I keep getting error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ...
```

I am working on Microsoft Visual Studio 2015;

Comment: provide implementation of template function in header file

Comment: `foo::~foo(); {` and `foo::foo(); {` look pretty bad, remove the semicolons for a start

Comment: @JHobern yeah... that was typo... ^^